# equal the image size despite different patterns

Tags: html, css

i've been trying for a long time to equal the image sizes on these 3 images. I know i could equal it by applying a left and right padding on the left and right column. How can i equal the sizes of the images and columns even though different padding is applied?

As you can see below the center column/image is smaller than the other two due to padding differences. How can this be solved without creating another padding on the left and right side of the right and left columns, since that won't work with the current design

```css
.container-col {
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.column-left,
.column-right,
.column-center {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.column-left {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px 20px 0em;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0em 20px 8px;
}
.column-center {
  padding: 0 8px 20px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-right-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.column-center {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  border-right-color: #aaa;
}
.top-div {
  height: auto;
}
.bottom-div {
  line-height: 18px;
  height: auto;
}
.bottom-div h5 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.game-table {
  border-top: 1px dotted #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.game-item {
  padding: 8px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
  height: auto;
}
.game-home {
  float: left;
  width: 44%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  text-align: right;
}
.game-vs {
  width: 8%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.game-away {
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="container-col">
  <div></div>
  <div class="column-center">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container-col {
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.column-left,
.column-right,
.column-center {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.column-left {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px 20px 0em;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0em 20px 8px;
}
.column-center {
  padding: 0 8px 20px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-right-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.column-center {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  border-right-color: #aaa;
}
.top-div {
  height: auto;
}
.bottom-div {
  line-height: 18px;
  height: auto;
}
.bottom-div h5 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.game-table {
  border-top: 1px dotted #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.game-item {
  padding: 8px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
  height: auto;
}
.game-home {
  float: left;
  width: 44%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  text-align: right;
}
.game-vs {
  width: 8%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.game-away {
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-col">
  <div></div>
  <div class="column-center">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <div class="top-div">
      <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/523ce201e4b0cd883dbb8bbf/t/53bf2302e4b06e125c374401/1405035267633/profile-icon.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div">
      <h5>headline</h5>

      <div class="game-table">
        <div class="game-item">
          <div class="game-home">home Team</div>
          <div class="game-vs">Vs.</div>
          <div class="game-away">away team</div>
        </div>
      </div>Nibh voluptua eleifend sed ne, ex melius maiorum vix, ea case percipit sit. Quo in scripta prodesset, ex nam sonet theophrastus. Read More ...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can try by fixing the height of the image:

```
.top-div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;// a desired one.
}
```

Comment: but wont the width of columsn still be different?

Comment: yes it will be different for sure,depending on the image.

Comment: you can fix that also by adding fixed value like: 300px or something.100% means the image actual size.

Comment: fixed value for the width?

Comment: yes if you want to make all the images shown with identical shape you have to fix the height and width i guess.

Comment: yes okay i could do that but would that not create issues regarding responsiveness

Comment: it will be negotiable and to make images of same size you have to do that otherwise you have to set it based on the div width and height.

Comment: and to clear you doubt all the sites do control the width and height of images or they create identical shape images.